# Constructing a distribution that maximizes the ratio of expectations

Tags: probability-theory, real-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $f_0$ be a bounded, infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Also let $f_1$ be bounded, positive and infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_0(x)<f_1(x)$ for all $x$. I am curious about the following. Consider the ratio of expectations
$$R(F_X):=\frac{E[f_0(X)]}{E[f_1(X)]}=\frac{\int f_0(x) \, dF_X}{\int f_1(x) \, dF_X},$$
where both expectations are taken with respect to the same distribution. Is there a way to construct a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ that maximizes the above ratio?
A trivial upper bound on $R(F_X)$ can be constructed as $\frac{\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}{f_0(x)}}{\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}{f_1(x)}}$. However, this bound is very conservative, especially if the infimum in the denominator can be very small.
I have not been able to find any useful references online. I would appreciate if anybody could point me to some useful sources.

Comment: Find the point of the maximum of $f_0(x)/f(x)$ (if it exists) and place the whole mass there. Obviously, you cannot do better.

Comment: @fedja, why can't I do better?

Comment: Hah? If $f_0\le Kf$ everywhere, then $Ef_0(X)\le K Ef(X)$, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, maximizing the ratio as a whole gives another upper bound $K$, that's clear, but how do we know that there is no $F_X$ that does better? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452131/show-that-max-p-x-x-in-0-1-left-frac-mathbbe-fx-mathbb

Comment: Thank you, that's indeed straightforward, my bad.